# Pydantic - ForwardRef in FieldInfo not updated by update_forward_refs

Tags: python, pydantic

Given the following:

```
from typing import ForwardRef
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


ClassB = ForwardRef('B', is_class=True)

class A(BaseModel):
    b: ClassB = Field(default_factory=ClassB)
    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True

class B:
    pass

A.update_forward_refs()
A.construct()
```

I get an error on `A.construct()`:

```
File "pydantic_forward_ref.py", line 16, in <module>
    A.construct()
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 600, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.construct
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 439, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.get_default
TypeError: 'ForwardRef' object is not callable
```

The ForwardRef in field type is updated as expected:

```
print(A.__fields__['b'].type_)
<class '__main__.B'>
```

but the ForwardRef in field_info is not:

```
print(A.__fields__['b'].field_info.default_factory)
ForwardRef('B')
```

How can I update the ForwardRef in `field_info` to enable default construction of `A`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an ideal solution as it accesses Pydantic internals, but when the referenced objects are defined in a separate module then `ForwardRef`s in `default_factory` can be resolved via the following (assuming the referenced class is defined in the global or local namespace of the module):

```
for k, v in A.__fields__.items():
    if isinstance(v.default_factory, ForwardRef):
        evaluated_ref = v.default_factory._evaluate(
            globalns=globals(),
            localns=locals(),
            recursive_guard=frozenset(),
        )
        v.default_factory = evaluated_ref
        v.field_info.default_factory = evaluated_ref
```

This is useful when `A` and `B` are part of a package and the `ForwardRef`s are being resolved in `__init__.py`

Answer (score 1):

`ForwardRef` is part of the type hinting mechanism, but you're trying to use it as an actual class. You can't do that.

The simplest solution here is to define `class B` before `class A`:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class B:
    pass

class A(BaseModel):
    b: B = Field(default_factory=B)
    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True

A.update_forward_refs()
A.construct()
```

Alternatively, you can make use of [postponed annotations](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/postponed_annotations/) and a `lambda` expression if it's important to keep the existing definition order:

```
from __future__ import annotations

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class A(BaseModel):
    b: B = Field(default_factory=lambda: B)

    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True


class B:
    pass


A.update_forward_refs()
A.construct()
```

Both of the above solutions produce the same result.

Comment: Order is important in my case. The example in the question was just a simplified version of my scenario. There are circular dependencies between models that I'd love to remove, but am not able to, so I'm resorting to ForwardRefs and updating them in `__init__.py`. It appears that `b` is still a ForwardRef after construction in the lambda example. Is there a way to make it a `class B`?

Comment: My mistake, I tried adding the lambda with the current ForwardRef implementation. It's resolved as expected with the `annotations` import. In my real scenario `class B` is defined in another module. Do you know if there's a way to resolve the future annotations in that scenario?